# How to check for newer updates every 10 seconds in the database?

Tags: javascript, php

I only want a specific division called 'footer' within my home.php file to refresh and display the most recent time update from my database every 30 seconds. I have tried but did not succeed. Can anyone advice how to do?

Here is part of my home.php code:

```
<div id="footer" style="text-align:right; font-size:0.8em; color:red;">
    <?php 
        echo "Last Update: " .$assignments[0]->time_updated;
    ?>
</div>
```

js code:

```
function getTime(){
    $('#footer').load('home.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

getTime(); 
setInterval(function(){
    getTime() 
}, 30000);
```

Comment: make ajax request and just change the time only not whole footer. On each ajax request call to a php file which return you the latest data from your DB.

Comment: I still do not know how to approach this with ajax. Can you provide more support on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way the value will not be updated, because to get latest value you need to refresh whole page. TO do this, the best way would be
1) First create a PHP file that query db and get latest time, 
2) Make ajax request to that PHP file to get the latest time 
3) And change the text of the footer.

For example something like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getTime(){
        //var some_id = $("#some_id").val();// you can get values and pass to your PHP script too
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", //or POST how you define your PHP file to get latest date
            url: get_latest_date.php,
            //data: "id="+some_id, //you can pass some data like this
            success: function(msg){
                $("#footer").html(msg); //If you just simple echo latest value form your PHP file
            }

        })
    }

    getTime(); 
    setInterval(function(){
        getTime() 
    }, 30000);
});
```

Create a file called `get_latest_date.php` and simply echo the latest time from DB.
**get_latest_date.php**

```
<?php 
echo date("H:i:s");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.